# Título da aba "com recompensa" não traduzido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Estive passando por todas as abas do SOpt para encontrar novos tipos de perguntas, quando me deparei com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente, o título da aba das perguntas com recompensa não está traduzido. Lembro-me de já ter visto o título traduzido, então alguma coisa deve ter sido mudada na página. Também me deparei com o mesmo problema na aba de perguntas não respondidas com minhas tags, mas nesta aba, o título da aba e o título principal não estão traduzidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acabei de definir traduções para *"Bountied Questions"* no [Traducir](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Bountied%20questions). *"Unanswered questions in my watched tags"* está [pendente](https://pt.traducir.win/string/11532). *"Questions with my tags"* [também](https://pt.traducir.win/string/10012).

Você mesmo pode entrar no Traducir e dar suas sugestões de traduções para alguns buracos que aparecem por aqui. E então, a tradução será analisada e poderá entrar em vigor na próxima build.

Comment: Não sabia desta, vou utilizar caso eu encontre mais alguma falta de tradução.